# Getting data from JSF controller to EJB

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, ejb

A JSF application used to send emails periodically. Now it is necessary to include details of logged users. 
I have a stateless EJB that sends the emails.Is there anyway go get the details of logged user in to the stateless EJB. 
Can I inject a named beans (JSF Controller) in to the EJB?

Comment: Note that the dupe is **your own question**, asked 5 years ago.

Comment: My ignorance made me laugh for some time. Thank you very  much.